# What is the meaning of $c+i\times\infty$ when integrating a complex function

Tags: complex-integration

My friend gave me a complex function to plot in MATLAB. The problem is that the integration interval or path (I do not know much about complex analysis so I don't know which is correct here path or interval) is from $c-i\times\infty$ to $c+i\times\infty$. Now what to do with that? I used `integral` function in MATLAB and instead of $\infty$ I used a number say 10. but I am not sure doing this is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

These integral bounds just mean
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{c-ti}^{c+ti}f(z)dz$$
so taking some finite $t\in\mathbb{R}$ sufficiently large should give an accurate result.

Comment: $ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(c+iy) diy = i \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(c+iy) dy$